# Jquery .click(function() { }); Does not work on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click

```
$(".down").click(function() { 
    $("#sideRight")
       .animate({top: "305"}, 350);
    });
```

Dont work on IE9 (and earlier versions of IE)
How can it be fixed?

http://goo.gl/5b82w (there is div class="down" on top menu. Click on this divs must animate right column)

Comment: In general it is more helpful if you can you explain what you mean when you say "Dont work". What doesn't work, is there an error, does it not behave as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code

```
$(function(){
   $('.down').on("click", function (e) { 
     $("#sideRight")
       .animate({top: "305"}, 350);
   });
});
```